# Compare a processing instruction and get the file name

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm writing an XSLT in which I need to see if a value is in preprocessing instruction. In my XML, the preprocessing looks like below.

```
 <?xpp MAIN;1;1;0;0;69;0;0?>
```

**Sample XML**

```
<root>
    <?xpp MAIN;1;0;0;0;73;0;0?>
    <preface role="guideline">
        <title>title</title>
        <section role="group">
            <para>data</para>
        </section>
        <section role="group">
            <title>
                <?xpp lp;0.5p?>Licences</title>
            <itemizedlist mark="bullet">
                <listitem>
                    <para>itemdata</para>
                </listitem>
            </itemizedlist>
        </section>
        <section role="group">
            <title>
                <?xpp lp;0.5p?>Letters to the Editor</title>
            <itemizedlist mark="bullet">
                <listitem>
                    <para><?xpp MAIN;1;0;0;0;74;0;0?>item data</para>
                </listitem>
            </itemizedlist>
        </section>
    </preface>
</root>
```

**Sample1 XML**

```
<root>
    <?xpp MAIN;1;0;0;0;83;0;0?>
    <preface role="guideline">
        <title>title</title>
        <section role="group">
            <para>data</para>
        </section>
        <section role="group">
            <title>
                <?xpp lp;0.5p?>Licences</title>
            <itemizedlist mark="bullet">
                <listitem>
                    <para>itemdata</para>
                </listitem>
            </itemizedlist>
        </section>
        <section role="group">
            <title>
                <?xpp lp;0.5p?>Letters to the Editor</title>
            <itemizedlist mark="bullet">
                <listitem>
                    <para><?xpp MAIN;1;0;0;0;84;0;0?>item data</para>
                </listitem>
            </itemizedlist>
        </section>
    </preface>
</root>
```

For the below XML, I need to do the task of going through files and checking for the data. The Above sample XML and Sample1 XML are the files that I've loop through.

```
<root>
<table frame="none" tabstyle="wrap4">
    <tgroup cols="4">
        <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="10*"/>
        <colspec colnum="2" colname="COLSPEC0" colwidth="10.00*"/>
        <colspec colnum="3" colname="col2" colwidth="275*"/>
        <colspec colnum="4" colname="col3" colwidth="15*"/>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0">Text1</entry>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0"/>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0"/>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0" align="right">75</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0">Text2</entry>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0"/>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0"/>
                <entry colsep="0" rowsep="0" align="right">84</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
</root>
```

Here first I'm trying to loop through all the files available, in each file, look for the preprocessing containing `MAIN` in it and then see if my value is present in that preprocessing instruction. Below is my XSLT block.

```
<xsl:template match="entry[@align='right']" mode="y">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="prent" select="document(document('file:///C:\Users\userId\Desktop\Proview\AUS Journal\02FEB/title.xml')/entry/file/@name)/*[contains(//root/processing-instruction('xpp')[contains(.,'MAIN')],regex-group(1))]/substring-before(tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()], '.')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="cha">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$prent"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="size">
                    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($cha)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="conct">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($cha,'/pg_',.)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <a href="{$conct}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                </a>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

When I run this I get the below error.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/userId/Desktop/Proview/AUS%20Journal/02FEB/XSLT/Journal.xsl:674: Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one').
```

please let me know how can I fix this and get job done.

Thanks

Comment: Please add an XML sample so that we can run some code.

Comment: Which is the line that gives the error? Does the error message not give more details as to which function (e.g. `contains`) is called with the wrong arguments? Are there files where `//root/processing-instruction('xpp')` could find more than one processing instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try whether changing the step

```
*[contains(//root/processing-instruction('xpp')[contains(.,'MAIN')],regex-group(1))]
```

to

```
*[//root/processing-instruction('xpp')[contains(.,'MAIN')][contains(., regex-group(1))]]
```

fixes the problem.